# backgrounded App peridiocal Handler Wierd behaviour

Tags: android, triggers

I have a `Handler` that simply writes "triggered" to a file once triggered. The `Handler` is triggered every 5 seconds for testing. This is strange:
when I launch the App and the App is foregrounded, the `Handler` is behaving correctly every 5 seconds. If the App is backgrounded and the phone is plugged in the laptop, I can see through logcat that everything is working fine. However, when I remove the phone cable and the app is backgrounded(not closed) then something goes wrong with the timer!

Here is my code:

```
public void trigger()
{
    RZTestHandler.removeCallbacks(RZTestTask);
    RZTestHandler.postDelayed(RZTestTask, 5000);
}

private Handler RZTestHandler  = new Handler();

private Runnable RZTestTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        globalVariables.AppLogging("triggered"); //simply writes to file
        Log.d(TAG,"Triggered");
        trigger();
    }
};
```

Called from Activity onCreate():

```
trigger();
```

AppLogging method runs the following code:

```
File oFile = new File(filePath);
if (!oFile.exists()) {
    oFile.createNewFile();
}
if (oFile.canWrite()) {
    BufferedWriter oWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath),true));
    oWriter.newLine();
    oWriter.write (" ###"+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date())+":Activity:"+sContent +" \n\r"); 
    oWriter.close();
}
```

The output

> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:24 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:29 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:34 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:39 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:45 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:50 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:26:55 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:00 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:05 PM:Activity:triggered   //backgrounded and detached
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:14 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:27 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:33 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:46 PM:Activity:triggered   // reattached and foregrounded
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:51 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:27:56 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:28:01 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:28:06 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:28:11 PM:Activity:triggered
>
> #### 19/01/2016 03:28:16 PM:Activity:triggered

Comment: What's sss();? Plz provide more code.

Comment: globalVariables.AppLogging("triggered"); I think it costs more time becasue you app is not in foregrounded.

Comment: also i tried increasing the timer to 15 seconds and more not just 5 seconds and had the same behaviour

Comment: Can you try to remove globalVariables.AppLogging("triggered");?

Comment: You has Log.d(TAG,"Triggered"); to know if it is triggering at the correct time.

Comment: tried that now still the same. there was more than 10 seconds difference in some of the logs

Comment: Did your mobile's screen is closed?

Comment: yes the app is backgrounded and the mobile screen is off

Comment: You can try to open screen.Hander.postDelay don't work fine when mobile goes to sleep.

Comment: what should i use to handle this? i tried alarm manager but also sometimes it lags

Comment: I don't really know.It says that use type RTC_WAKEUP in setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation).Did you try Timer and TimerTask?

Comment: no these are the remaining ones lol thanks for your help anyway man appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I created a service in the following way and used PowerManager.WakeLock:

```
 public class PeriodicalTimerService extends Service
    {


        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)MyApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        public static Handler RZTestHandler  = new Handler();

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            PeriodicalTriggerStarter();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
        private Runnable RZTestTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                boolean backgrounded = globalVariables.isApplicationSentToBackground();


                if(GlobalVariables.IsSignedIn)
                {
                    if (GlobalVariables.DownloadServiceCanStart)
                    {
                        GlobalVariables.DownloadServiceCanStart=false;
                        StartStopService.StartDownloadService(MyApplication.getContext());
                    }
                    if (wakeLock!=null && wakeLock.isHeld())
                    {
                        wakeLock.release();
                    }
                    Repeater();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld())
                    {
                        wakeLock.release();
                    }
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        };

        public void Repeater() {
            wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "RSZWakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();

            if (RZTestHandler == null)
            {
                RZTestHandler = new Handler();
            }

            RZTestHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            RZTestHandler.postDelayed(RZTestTask, Long.parseLong(globalVariables.GetSharedStringValue("serviceTimer")));
        }
        public void PeriodicalTriggerStarter()
        {
            if (RZTestHandler == null)
            {
                RZTestHandler = new Handler();
            }

            RZTestHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            RZTestHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(RZTestTask);
        }
    }
```